# memory leak - gdiplus.dll brushes

Tags: c#, memory, memory-leaks

My Application is using 5 GB to 6 GB of memory. We have run IIS debug diagnostics, and it shows the following:

GdiPlus.dll is responsible for 2.49 GBytes worth of outstanding allocations. The following are the top 2 memory consuming functions:

GdiPlus!GpMemoryBitmap::AllocBitmapData+c2: 2.47 GBytes worth of outstanding allocations.
GdiPlus!EpScanBitmap::Start+212: 6.79 MBytes worth of outstanding allocations.

This was detected in w3wp.exe_*Projectname-2*_PID_*28824*_Date__03_10_2012__Time_03_15_14PM_*457*_Leak Dump - Private Bytes.dmp

what is causing this leak?  This is due to brushes.

Please give some idea/ or how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you `Dispose()`-ing your resources properly?

Comment: I am trying to find how to locate this issue. How do I find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably forgetting to release GDI handles (bitmaps, brushes, pens, etc). Most GDI objects implement `IDisposable`, and you should always call the `Dispose` method when you're done using these objects. The `using` statement can help with that:

```
using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
{

    ...

} // b.Dispose is called automatically here
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say (from the alocator info that you supplied) that you don't kill your bitmaps.  Every GDI+ object is `IDisposable`, so `Dispose()` it or use `using` keyword as suggested.